# Fastest way to read public file periodically over http

Tags: java, http

Currently I read a *3rd party* public file over http by polling it every say 30s through my Java project.

The public file usually changes every few seconds or minutes.

**What is the best way to receive faster updates from the file?**
I considered using long-polling or keeping connection alive, but not sure if it needs server support (which is not in my control)
Another idea was to use the If-Modified-Since header, so that I wont need to parse the stream.

Or should I just be polling faster or is there a better way (with or without http)?

Comment: Come off it folks. Nothing unclear about this question.

Comment: The way would be support from the server, for example a websocket stream (this is what stack exchange uses) or a custom protocol

Comment: Yes unfortunately the server is not under my control. Else socket would have been helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use the HEAD request as often as necessary to find out when the file has changed, and only use GET when you know the content differs. Or, if you trust the target system to return it, do nothing when you get HTTP `304 Not Modified`.

Comment: Thanks EJP! Is requesting for HEAD every say 2-5s an overkill from a server load perspective?

Comment: Unanswerable. You have to strike a balance between timeliness and overload. Do you really need to check every 2s? 5s?

Comment: Its tricky, since I would not know (its unpredictable) when the server file would be updated and its important to be able to read the new data from that file as soon as it has changed.

Comment: Unimplementable with HTTP, as you have to poll. Either accept a timeliness/overload compromise or use different technology. I would review the requirement. Applications that use files for IPC are for the 1970s. Why isn't it a database?